# Обновление указателей типа char в СИ

Tags: c, указатели, char

Всем добрый день!

У меня возник такой вопрос. Как можно обновлять указатель с типом `char` в бесконечном цикле. Если в функции создаю `char *user=malloc(sizeof(char)*400*2);`, затем отправляю этот указатель во вторую функцию, где он заполняется данными и возвращает обратно в мою функцию уже полученные данные, которые потом я записываю в базу данных. Но эти данные должны обновляться через каждые 5 секунд, поэтому после записи в базу данных я очищаю свой указатель. Но у меня возникла проблема, что когда уже очищенный указатель заходит снова во вторую функцию для получения новых данных, то эти  данные просто приписываются к предыдущим данным, хотя я очищала указатель.

вот эта функция находится в бесконечном цикле

```
int info(ST_CN conn)
{
    DB_CP *cp = malloc(sizeof(DB_CP));
    ST_CN *conn = malloc(sizeof(ST_CN));

    db_get_conn_params(cp);
    db_connect(cp, conn);
    char *user=malloc(sizeof(char)*419*2);
    w_block( &user);   //вторая функция куда я отправляю свой указатель
    char *query = "update notepad set valu=? where kfield='info';";
    db_query(conn, query);

    MYSQL_BIND *result = malloc(sizeof(MYSQL_BIND));
    unsigned long *clen = malloc(sizeof(unsigned long));
    int rtypes[] = {MYSQL_TYPE_STRING};
    db_bind_params( conn, result, rtypes, clen, 1, user);
    clen[0] = strlen(user);
    db_execute(conn);
    db_close(conn);
    *user='\0';
    free(user);
    free(result);
    free(clen);
}


w_block(char **user)
{
    //длинный длинный код вначале
    .................
    //потом внутри for опять большой код и заполнение указателя под конец
    for(....)
    {
        ...........
        .........
        ............

        strcat(*user, ut_user);
        strcat(*user, " ");
        strcat(*user, p);
        strcat(*user, ",");
    }
    (*user)[strlen(*user)-1]='\0';
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Что значит "очищала указатель"? И вообще - можно посмотреть какой-то код, что вы делаете?

Comment: Очищала указатель значит обнуливала его, удаляла данные

Comment: Приведите код. Потому что по вашим словам получается, что вы вообще передаете в функцию нулевой указатель :) Пока у меня огромные подозрения, что вы вообще некорректно работаете с памятью. Развейте мои сомнения...

Comment: Все скинула код:)

Comment: У вас в цикле пять раз ребенка подбрасывают (malloc) и только три раза ловят (free). Утечка мозгов (памяти)... И - у вас после `malloc` в данных мусор - это никак не влияет на работу `w_block` и всех `db_...`? Туда можно передавать мусор? И еще - вот это - `*user='\0';` - перед освобождением - пустые хлопоты по дороге в казенный дом (освобожденную память)...

Comment: а что предлагаете сделать? как можно это исправить?

Comment: "*очищенный указатель заходит снова во вторую функцию для получения новых данных, то эти данные просто приписываются к предыдущим данным*" - вот это самое интересное - добавление данных во второй функции - вы ведь и не показали. Да она у вас вообще может само значение указателя `user` менять...

Comment: вот функция w_block

Comment: Я перенес ваш код из вашего ответа в вопрос - удалите этот лишний ответ, pls...

Answer (score 0):

Ну вот все и выяснилось.

Вместо первого обращения

```
strcat(*user, ut_user);
```

т.е. дописывания к какому-то мусору, используйте

```
strcpy(*user, ut_user);
```

или хотя бы занулите `(*user)[0]` перед началом работы.

Это не снимает вопроса с утечками памяти в `info()` и еще одного вопроса - зачем вы передаете в `w_block()` указатель на переменную-указатель? Вы же ее менять не собираетесь? Передавайте в нее просто `char*` - как минимум не придется везде звездочку перед `user` ставить :)

Comment: Я передаю указатель, т.к. мне же надо полученные данные вернуть в функцию info(). А если просто символьную переменную отправить, то он же не будет возвращать данные.

Comment: @Lam Одной звездочки уже достаточно, это же указатель, который указывает на нужную область памяти, значит в эту область и произойдет запись. Вот если бы ни одной звездочки не было бы, то это был бы 1 байт, который был бы в стеке и был бы потерян после вызова функции

Comment: Ну, вам уже ответили... Ну как, заработало?

Comment: Да заработало! Спасибо:)

Comment: Тогда закрывайте вопрос, пометив ответ как принятый (птичка слева от ответа). Здесь "спасибо" говорят примерно таким образом :)